# Nginx picking up wrong directory from configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I have written the nginx config file but somehow nginx is looking for the directory `/pipelines/videos/neuralAI.mp4` which doesn't exists instead of looking for the `/pipelines/assets/neuralAI.mp4` . Any help would be appreciated.

```
  location /videos/ {
    access_by_lua_block {
        if(ngx.var.maintenance == "on") then
            local authorize = require("authorize") 
            local maintenance = ngx.var.maintenance
            authorize.validate_access(nil, nil, "/videos", "{DEPLOYMENT}", maintenance) 
        end
    }
    root /pipelines;
    proxy_temp_path /usr/local/openresty/nginx/temp/proxy_temp;
    client_body_temp_path /usr/local/openresty/nginx/temp/client_body_temp;
    fastcgi_temp_path /usr/local/openresty/nginx/temp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /usr/local/openresty/nginx/temp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /usr/local/openresty/nginx/temp/scgi_temp;
    access_log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log;
    error_log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log;
  }
```

**Error in Log File:**

```
9:26:17 [error] 33#33: *11 open() "/pipelines/videos/neuralAI.mp4" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.172.1, server: , request: "GET /videos/neuralAI.mp4 HTTP/1.1", host: "route.corp.com"
```

**Directory:**

```
bash-4.2# pwd
/pipelines/assets
bash-4.2# ls -l 
total 26068
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1000 26692604 June 17 19:24 neuralAI.mp4
bash-4.2#
```

Thank You

Comment: Why are you expecting the file will be searched in the `/pipelines/assets` directory? That config doing exactly what you tell it to do. Do you see any `assets` word in your config?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue using alias instead of root